# topology for an unmanaged switch (firewall)

Tags: switch, nat, firewall, voip, sip

I'm considering an **unmanaged** switch.  My understanding is that many of these devices explicitly lack a firewall.  In that case, what do you use as a firewall?

I suppose one option would be to use a Linux PC as a firewall, or, when I look on Amazon I see different firewalls for sale.  However, the hardware based firewalls all have multiple ports.  Or not?

Doesn't that introduce double NAT?  I prefer to keep the switch separate from the firewall, whether that's an appliance or Linux distro.  This is in the context of a small VoIP office, maybe fifteen lines.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: if the pc's connect to the switch, what does the switch connect to?  the firewall?  isn't that double NAT?

Comment: You do not have to NAT from a switch, nor should you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to purchase a firewall, you need to look for a firewall *or* a router with firewall functionality built in.  A switch is not a firewall.

NAT is generally happening at L3, so while I suppose some switches could and do support it, none I know of do.  Again, NAT is something that generally would occur at a router.

Hardware-based firewalls have multiple ports, yes.  One or two might be for WAN links.  This is where you'd connect the firewall to the outside world in some fashion.  The chassis will also have one or more LAN ports.  Here's where your internal network connects.  If you need a switch, it will sit between the firewall/router's LAN port and your office machines.

Comment: Typically, then it's modem=>firewall;firewall=>switch and then **everything else** into the switch?  contrast with http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Ekiga_as_an_Asterisk_client